How to solve this uploading Target Image in vuforia wrong_color_model?
How to solve this uploading Target Image in vuforia wrong_color_model?
What's also the cause for this to happen?
I'm just trying to start studying AR development for my 3D art to present.
Thanks
Please help me Solve for the problem

The message “Wrong_Color_Model” that you see when adding your image to Vuforia indicates that the image you are trying to upload is not in the correct color model. Vuforia requires images to be in the RGB (Red, Green, Blue) color model to be used as targets.
Solution:
1.  Check the color model of your image:
•   It is possible that the image is currently in CMYK (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black) or Grayscale, which are commonly used in printing. You need to convert your image to RGB.
2.  Convert the image to RGB:
•   Open your image in an image editing software like Adobe Photoshop or GIMP.
•   In Photoshop, go to the Image > Mode menu and select RGB Color.
•   In GIMP, you can do the same via Image > Mode > RGB.
•   Then save your image in .png or .jpg format and try adding it to Vuforia again.
3.  Try uploading the image to Vuforia again:
•   After converting the image to RGB, try adding it as an “Image Target” in Vuforia again. This should resolve the issue.

This should help you resolve the issue with Vuforia. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

This error can even occur having RGB images. In my case it was a screenshot taken with OSX.
For me I could in photoshop use Edit > Assign Profile.

There I changed from Profile: Display to Working RGB: sRGB IEC61966-2.1.


if these don't work, try a other format instead. I was uploading .png files but when i switched to .jpg files it worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
